# Programatically Creating Pivot Table in MS Excel With Multiple Sheets as Source Via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, vba, excel

I have more than one million rows of data, I want to present that in in MS Excel as Pivot table.

But MS Excel having 1048756 rows only, my data is exceeding sheet range.

Is there any possibility to build pivot with data having more than one million records?

Comment: Group the rows in VS then divide the groups so data fits on page.

Comment: I did't got your answer could you elaborate

Comment: You need an OLAP cube for that. Once you have that, Excel can show a pivot table.

Comment: @Sam wow really? can you share the steps to do that?

Comment: Pivot table pivots on data in certain columns.  So if you group the sql query results on same columns as the pivot you will be able to split the data into rows less than 1048756.  Then put each group(s) on a separate page in excel.

Comment: OLAP cubes is something you need to study on your own. Too big to handle here.

Comment: @Sam no, you don't *need* an OLAP cube for that.

Comment: @Mat'sMug True.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than a million rows of data, that data doesn't belong in Excel - don't pivot off a `Range`, pivot off a *query* instead.

You can easily get a pivot table to feed from a remote source instead of a range of cells.

From the [Data] Ribbon tab, under the [Get External Data] group, select [From SQL Server] from the [From Other Sources] drop-down:

[image: Data - Get External Data - From Other Sources - From SQL Server]

Specify your connection details - you'll have a server-side *Table* or *View* that yields the records you want to pivot against.

When the *Import Data* dialog comes up, select **PivotTable Report**:

[image: "Select how you want to view this data in your workbook"]

The data now lives in the pivot cache, not on your worksheet.

If you have an OLAP cube rather than a table or view, simply pick "From Analysis Services" instead of "From SQL Server" in the *From Other Sources* dropdown.

Record a macro while doing this, to get code to do it programmatically.

Comment: Can we give data source as C# Data Table?

Comment: @RamaKrishna Excel doesn't speak C# or .NET, so no. But your `DataTable` came from somewhere - take that source and make it a view, then you can use C#/VSTO to do what you want, by translating the macro-recorder code from VBA to C# (which is well beyond the scope of your question BTW)